# How to pick records having duplicate value type in a column - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table "xyz", it has 3 columns (id, tranxId, type), type can be either credit or debit.

Now, I want to be able to pull tranxId where type of credit/debit appears more than once.

[image: This is a sample of my table]

My expected result should be more like:

1. FR123    credit    3
2. FR124    credit    2
3. FR123    debit     2
   ...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below -

```
select tranxId, type,count(*)
from tablename
group by tranxId, type
having count(*)>1
```

Comment: Thanks for this invaluable input. But, can we have it display these transactions like:

1.  FR123   credit  [date]
2.  FR123   credit  [date]
3.  FR123   credit  [date]
4.  FR124   debit   [date]
5.  FR124   debit   [date]
...

Comment: @DegodTestra, could you please add it to your question